# Submitting 50 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage - spark log explanation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I submit the spark streaming job it creates a job with 70 tasks and its getting completed like in 2 seconds. Then it starts up the same job with one task running which is the desired behaviour. The job is receiving mq data via a custom receiver.

The jar I submit only contains a MQ custom reciever and kafka sink. No processors. It just send what has been received to mq to kafka.

I could found following in the spark log. 
But other than that I have no idea why it creates such amount of tasks at the initiation.

INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Submitting 50 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at start at Streaming.java:59) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is there a way to solve this or make the run faster?. Or can we reduce this? Is this dependent on the shuffle partition i have mention or all the maps im calling on spark dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

Submitting 50 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 occurs when there are Fetch Failure happening while fetching intermediate shuffle results from External Shuffle Service during Stage 1.

This Triggers a re-attempt of the taskset to recalculate the shuffle map outputs followed by retrigger of current tasks